# Capturing (git) command output in github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to capture the output of this git command (or any for that matter).

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --patch-with-raw -r HEAD  # HEAD or some commit SHA
```

However, unlike an `echo`, the following command does not log any output in the GitHub actions log. Nor does it streams the output to a variable. On my local, the same command logs the changes made in the last commit.

```
# result is empty
result=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --patch-with-raw -r HEAD)
```

What am I missing? How do I capture the output of the above git command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the [checkout action](https://github.com/actions/checkout) to checkout your code? `git diff-tree` probably doesn't output anything if you're not fetching the history. Try

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```

Comment: I was fooled by default `fetch-depth: 1` to bear the latest commit. Changed to `5` for now and it works. Happy tears. Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Probably something alike this... in every case with `echo`:

```
echo $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --patch-with-raw -r HEAD)
```

Comment: No luck: https://imgur.com/a/gJQzUkD

You can see that `git status` command logs output but the other `git diff-tree ...` does not. FYI, on my local, the same command logs the changes made in the last commit.